# Blender: export to minilight?

Tags: python, 3d, blender

[MiniLight](http://www.hxa.name/minilight/) is a minimal global illumination renderer, written as an exercise
in simplicity. Is there a plugin to export Blender scenes to MiniLight? Or is there another plugin that could be modified to do it?

The MiniLight format is pretty simple:

```
#MiniLight

iterations

imagewidth imageheight

viewposition viewdirection viewangle

skyemission groundreflection
trivertex0 trivertex1 trivertex2 reflectivity emitivity  
trivertex0 trivertex1 trivertex2 reflectivity emitivity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a Python script (based on the 'Raw faces' one by Anthony D'Agostino) to export triangle meshes from Blender to the MiniLight format. If anyone else needs it, I made it available on [GitHub](https://github.com/brunonery/scripts/blob/master/minilight_export.py).